# Why will the following code display No output?

Tags: c++

The following code was an MCQ question in a past university exam :
Can you explain to me the logic behind these two if statements too.

```
bool s=37%50<=0;
int x=2;
if(s)
if(x>0)
cout<<"Great";
else
cout<<"News";
```

This code dispalys:

```
a)Great News
b)Great
c)News
d)No output
```

Comment: details do matter. The code cannot possibly print "Great" or "News" to the screen when it only has strings "great" and "news"

Comment: What do you not understand? `%` is the modulus operator. 37%50 is 37.

Comment: `37%50` is not less or equall to `0`  so `s`is false and the second ìf`is never reached. But @largest_prime_is_463035818 is right :D

Comment: @ largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes I am aware of that , The question is actually with Uppercase 'G'&'N'.Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above is the same as writing:

```
bool s= 37%50 <= 0;
int x=2;

if(s) {
    if(x>0) {
        cout<<"great";
    } else {
        cout<<"news";
    }
}
```

Since `s` will be `false` (`37%50` is not `<= 0`), nothing will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

There would be no output for this question
first if is checking the bool value of s
37%50 = 37   % gives remainder when 36 is divided by 50 and the condition afterwards check if it's less than or equal to 0 which it is not, therefore,
..... s=False

therefore first we will not execute as its condition is false
and as there are no  angular brackets the second if is inside the first if therefore it too will not execute as first is not getting executed